# Combinatorics problem with minimizing number of operations

Tags: combinatorics

> There are candies in six baskets. One in the first, two in the second,
> etc. In the sixth basket, there are therefore six candies. In one
> step, one can add a candy to any two baskets, or remove a candy from
> any two baskets (if neither of these two baskets is empty). The goal
> is to get the same amount of candies in each basket after a number of
> steps. Is this possible to implement and if so, what is the minimum
> number of moves needed?

My attempt is:

The sum of candies in the six baskets is given by:
$$\sum_{n=1}^6 n=21.$$
Since $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, and 21 is an odd number, we cannot obtain an equal integer of elements in each box, since $\frac{21}{6}\in \mathbb{Q}$.

But this is not correct. I thought the total number had to stay fixed to 21 candies, but apparently it is not.  So if the sum in the formula is not fixed, and the only fixed number is 6 baskets, we should focus on the median number between 1 and 6, that is 3, for each basket?

Thanks

Comment: Just to clarify what a step is. Suppose there are only 2 baskets with the number of candies in each: (1, 2). Is it possible to reach all of these numbers: (2, 2), (1, 1), (2, 3), (0, 1) after the first step?

Comment: @MarkoLalovic You are allowed to add candies and subtract,
so my initial attempt ddid not disprove anything

Answer (score 4):

The sum of candies is initially odd. The two possible operations don’t change that. To get equal amount in each basket, the sum has to be even.

Comment: That is what I suggested too. But you can add apparently candies to the whole lot of candies.

Comment: We are allowed to add candies and subtract, so my initial attempt, which is the same as this answer,  did not disprove anything

Comment: @Luthier415Hz the invariance is not the sum, but its parity i.e. the sum being an odd number. Add or subtract two candies, the sum remains an odd number

Answer (score 2):

I will try to formalize this problem. Let $n$ be the number of baskets. Let $x_i$ be the number of candies in each basket. Let $\pmb{x}_{k} = (x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n)$ be the current state after $k$ moves. Define the objective function $f(\pmb{x}_{k}) = \sum_{i, j} |x_i - x_j|$. We can make a move and get into a next state $\pmb{x}_{k+1} = (x_1', x_2', \dots, x_n')$ in 4 possible ways, such that for some $i, j$, one of the following holds:

- $x_i' = x_i + 1$
- $x_i' = x_i - 1$
- $x_i' = x_i + 1$ and $x_j' = x_j + 1$
- $x_i' = x_i - 1$ and $x_j' = x_j - 1$

Given initial state $\pmb{x}_{0} = (1, 2, \dots n)$, the task is to reach a final state $\pmb{x}_{k}$ with $f(\pmb{x}_{k}) = 0$. The question is what is the minimum number of moves $k$ required. To answer this, we can calculate the shortest path:
$$
\pmb{x}_{0} \rightarrow \pmb{x}_{1} \rightarrow \dots \rightarrow \pmb{x}_{k}
$$

For $n = 2$, the initial state is $(1, 2)$ and we can move to final states $(2, 2)$ and $(1, 1)$ in one move. For $n = 6$ we can draw the graph, show in figure below to determine the shortest path is 5 moves. In general, I guess we need at least $n-1$ moves.

[image]

Comment: If we are allowed to subtract or add candy from only one basket then yes, it's possible. You need at least $n-1$ moves because the difference between the basket with the least amount and most amount of candies decreases by at most one per move.

Comment: Yes, that's a good point to finish my answer. Thank you for the comment.

Comment: @MarkoLalovic Note that
if every basket had the same
number of candies the total
would be even and that the
moves you can make does not
change the parity.

Comment: The parity can be changed using the definition of a move that I gave and used in my answer. Please specify what a move is by providing a definition or example as I asked in the comment to your question.

Comment: @MarkoLalovic A move is for example adding a candy to the first and second basket. that gives 2,3,3,4,5,6. Then we can either add or remove a candy from any two baskets, and we get 3,3,3,5,5,6, followed by 3,4,4,5,5,6 etc. So in fact the answer is no, it is impossible to reach a state where all baskets have the same number, because they will always change simultaneously.

Comment: Well, then what is wrong with Rezha Adrian Tanuharja's answer?

Comment: @MarkoLalovic that answer is the same as my assumption, and what is wrong with it, I have no idea. That is why I ask.