# Distribution of candies in 6 baskets

Tags: combinatorics

> There are candies in six baskets. One in the first, two in the second,
> etc. In the sixth basket, there are therefore six candies. In one
> step, one can add a candy to any two baskets, or remove a candy from
> any two baskets (if neither of these two baskets is empty). The goal
> is to get the same amount of candies in each basket after a number of
> steps. Is this possible to implement and if so, what is the minimum
> number of moves needed?

My answer:

In 5 moves, we can reach a number of 3 candies in 5 of 6 baskets. We add one to the first and second baskets in the first move. In the second move we add one to the first and subtract one to the fourth. We have now 2 equal baskets, with 3 candies in side. In the third move, we subtract one candy from the 5th and 6th basket, obtaining 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5 combination. In the fourth move, we remove one candy again from the two last baskets and obtain: 3,3,3,3,3,4. At last, we remove one candy from the sixth, but since all other baskets are equal, we must make one of the other baskets become of an unequal number. This will occur for any number of candies we want to obtain in the baskets. Why? This will occur because the allowed operation is to add or remove an odd number of candies to an even number of baskets, which will inevitably create a disparity among any selected three pairs (total 6 baskets).
This means that we cannot make all six baskets to be equal, without having to change one continuously. This is caused by that the number of candies in a box with even number of candies is dis-paired after a move, while the number of a box with odd number is made even after a move. Since there are 3 even numbered-containing baskets and 3 odd number containing baskets at the start, any number of moves will always leave a disparity in number of candies among the boxes.

But somehow, this answer is too vague. Is there a way to simplify this to a correct proof?

Thanks

Comment: Didn’t you ask this exact question some time ago? https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4727445/751970

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Combinatorics problem with minimizing number of operations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4727445/combinatorics-problem-with-minimizing-number-of-operations)

Comment: Rezha, that answer was wrong in those posts.

Comment: The answer in the duplicate is correct.  Every possible move preserves the parity of the number of candies.

Comment: @lulu I wonder if the key to this problem is that  that the operation adds or subtracts an odd number of candies , and we are considering an even number of baskets.

Comment: The key to the problem is the parity of the number of candies.  At each stage you either add or subtract two, so the parity never changes.

Comment: @lulu perfect statement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a total of $21$ candies. In each step you either subtract two or add two to your total count. So the total number of candies always stays odd. However, to get the same number of candies in each basket an even number of candies would be required. Hence the goal is not achievable.

Comment: This is what I thought too, but apparently, the total number of candies can increase to 23, 24, 25, etc.

Comment: I wonder if the key to this problem is that  that the operation adds or subtracts an odd number of candies , and we are considering an even number of baskets.

Comment: @Luthier415Hz if you can only add or subtract two candies at a time, how do you get a total of 24 candies?

Comment: Yes, that is wrong. But my point was that the total number of candies was not fixed

Comment: @Luthier415Hz Noone said the total number of candies is fixed. You start with $21$ and then add or subtract two. You always end up with an odd number of candies, be it $23$, $25$ or $19$.

Comment: Thanks Klaus, that clarified things.